# How do I grant email merge with templates to Dynamics CRM security role?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015, security-roles

I need to configure the security role. I am an administrator on the system. First, the user must be able to search for contacts in the extended search. According to selected contacts, he will launch a quick campaign. Prior to this, the user creates a template. Bulk will be on e-mail addresses of selected contacts. The author of the letter is a special user. Help set the security role with the minimum set of privileges required to perform the described scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Out-of-box Marketing Manager or Marketing Professional security role. They should suffice your need.

If its not enough, take the backup & customize those roles. Or Clone that role & add/elevate the needed privileges.